# Vue - v-html not displaying as HTML

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Here's a simple version of my application:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({ });

app.component('list', {
  props: {
    model: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  template: `<div v-for="widget in model.widgets">
    {{ widget.name }}
    <div v-html="widget.content"></div>
    <div v-html="widget.content2"></div>
    <div v-html="widget.content3"></div>
  </div>`
});

app.mount('#app');
```

I'm trying to pass the model as a property to my component, like so:

```html
<div id="app">
  <list :model="{
    &quot;widgets&quot;: [
      {
        &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Test&quot;,
        &quot;content&quot;: &quot;&lt;strong&gt;Bold Text&lt;/strong&gt;&quot;,
        &quot;content2&quot;: &quot;<strong>Bold Text</strong>&quot;,
        &quot;content3&quot;: '<strong>Bold Text</strong>'
      }
    ]
  }"></list>
</div>
```

However, it doesn't display the text as bold and I'm not sure why.

**Example snippet:**

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.component('list', {
  props: {
    model: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  template: `<div v-for="widget in model.widgets">
        {{ widget.name }}
      <div v-html="widget.content"></div>
      <div v-html="widget.content2"></div>
    </div>`
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <list :model="{
    &quot;widgets&quot;: [
      {
        &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Test&quot;,
        &quot;content&quot;: &quot;&lt;strong&gt;Bold Text&lt;/strong&gt;&quot;,
        &quot;content2&quot;: &quot;<strong>Bold Text</strong>&quot;
      }
    ]
  }"></list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use quotes as HTML entities, you can just structure it as normal JS:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.component('list', {
  props: {
    model: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  template: `<div v-for="widget in model.widgets">
        {{ widget.name }}
      <div v-html="widget.content"></div>
      <div v-html="widget.content2"></div>
    </div>`
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <list :model="{
    widgets: [
      {
        name: 'Test',
        content: '&lt;strong&gt;Bold Text&lt;/strong&gt;',
        content2: '<strong>Bold Text</strong>'
      }
    ]
  }"></list>
</div>
```

---

Though, if for some reason you needed to use HTML entities, `&quot;` doesn't work because it's already enclosed in quotes and terminates the string, i.e. `"Invalid "string""`.

If instead, you used single quotes, it would work as it's a valid string: `"Valid 'string'"`. So you could use `&apos;` in it's place:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.component('list', {
  props: {
    model: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  template: `<div v-for="widget in model.widgets">
        {{ widget.name }}
      <div v-html="widget.content"></div>
      <div v-html="widget.content2"></div>
    </div>`
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <list :model="{
    &apos;widgets&apos;: [
      {
        &apos;name&apos;: &apos;Test&apos;,
        &apos;content&apos;: &apos;&lt;strong&gt;Bold Text&lt;/strong&gt;&apos;,
        &apos;content2&apos;: &apos;<strong>Bold Text</strong>&apos;,
        &apos;content3&apos;: '<strong>Bold Text</strong>'
      }
    ]
  }"></list>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like a regression in Vue 3. I've filed an issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/3001.

Answer (score 0):

change your model data this way

```
:model="{
      widgets:[
              {
                name: 'Test&quot',
                content: '&lt;strong&gt;Bold Text&lt;/strong&gt;',
                content2: '<strong>Bold Text</strong>';
              }
         ]
}"
```